# Android: how can I display a string until the string reaches the end of a one-line textbox and display the rest in a different textbox?

Tags: java, android, string, textview, display

I like to think my title question is adequate, but the details are:

I have long strings (sentences in a story) to display and want it displayed in a number of textviews, with only one line in a box. If the string is too long, I want to truncate at a space or punctuation mark, then display the rest in another textview (or views if the string is really long). My display would have many textview, each with one piece of the string.

So, the question: **how can I truncate a string at the end of a textview** but not before? I do not know how many characters per line.

Second question: **how do I capture the remaining piece of sentence and display it in the next textview?**

The idea is to have a line of a complete sentence and a translation of the sentence appearing in the line below. If the sentence is longer than a single line, the truncated first part will have a truncated, translated line below it, then the remaining part of the original sentence below that, then the remaining part of the translated sentence below that. So, alternating lines of English text and Spanish text displayed.

Comment: You're going to have to do it all by hand, its not a feature of Android.  What part of it are you asking about?  Also, remember you're going to have to handle the case where the translation is MUCH larger than the original text.  I had to do something once where the word "double" in polish was like 15 letters and didn't fit in the space.

Comment: Clarifying questions added in bold (like my temerity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the line breaks, I suggest setting up a *TextView* that has the width of your on-display *TextViews* with `wrap_content` for its height. This will be an internal *TextView* that is for processing only and not for display. You will need to get the TextView to measure itself. [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws) can get you started. Of course, if the text is already displayed on-screen, you can just use that *TextView*.

Once the view is measured, you can get its internal layout which most likely is a [StaticLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout). (You can also use *StaticLayout* directly without the *TextView*.) Since the *StaticLayout* is a representation of the text display by the view and are the same lines of text that would display in the *TextView*, you can move them over directly to single-line, on-screen *TextViews* as long as those *TextViews* have the same characteristics as your internal one. *StaticLayout* has methods to retrieve individual lines of text.

There are details that you will have to work through, but that is the gist.

**Update:** I took the liberty of making a small [demo app](https://github.com/Cheticamp/TextViewLineSplitterDemo). This app takes a paragraph of text and splits it into the constituent lines. Those lines are then displayed on-screen with the original paragraph as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Checking this answer will take a while.  I am holding off giving you a check mark until I see how feasible it is.  I'm a rookie, so it will take a while; thank you for your input regardless.

Comment: Got very, very, very busy (lawsuit; do not sue anyone without engaging a lawyer first). The demo app is very convincing, so I'm going to give this a shot.  Sorry about the delay.